# How to display the list of values in text box when ever the replace string entered

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm new in front-end.I need to show the list of values whenever the user types the % in the text area.And from the list, the selected value must be appended in the text box.

for example:

> Hi %name how are you?

in the above string, the name is one of the list value.After appending the value it can allow the user to type normal text.

Comment: So you want someone write a widget for you.

Comment: @blackmiaool Not Like that I need Only suggestions or the way how to do that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to what you are looking for. Please ignore css

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ng app</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

        myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.actualData = [
                'John',
                'Dan',
                'Brown'
            ];

            $scope.viewList = function() {

                var templist = []

                if ($scope.val == '' || $scope.val == undefined) {
                    templist = [];
                } else if ($scope.val.indexOf('%') > -1) {
                    templist = $scope.actualData;
                }
                $scope.data = templist;
            }

            $scope.setData = function(value) {
                $scope.val = $scope.val.replace('%','') + " " + value;
                $scope.data = [];
            }



        })
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="search" ng-model="val" ng-change="viewList()" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="option in data" ng-click="setData(option)">{{option}}</li>
    <ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Check this plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/bz68dKK3izvCs7jcjX4C?p=preview, to see it in action